# What's a hinge called for a two-door corner cabinet?

Tags: doors, kitchens

I have kitchen cabinet in the corner where it has a revolving holder inside, which can spin so that it will use the space deep inside as well.  The door for it has 2 panels. There are 2 hinges connecting the 2 panels. One of the hinges seem to be broken, so I'm wondering what's the name for that connecting hinge, so that I could order the part.

Appreciate if anyone can give suggestion on the name I can use to search this part.

Here are the pictures for the cabinet and close-up look of the hinge.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EN-cwCVBGaAooCIw2TEwiJcKZVID4B30/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15L2h-nTdpOtDBQn6CT05-T7qqjcCfWTF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you now have two separate accounts; you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[Lazy Susan hinge](https://www.google.com/search?q=lazy%20susan%20hinge&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjmwOLrvbnqAhUb9qwKHaeMDgYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=lazy%20susan%20hinge&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHlDqEljqEmDHFGgAcAB4AIABXYgBXZIBATGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img&ei=5osDX-a1KZvsswWnmbow&bih=947&biw=1618&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850)" or "[corner cabinet hinge](https://www.google.com/search?q=corner%20cabinet%20hinge&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiD7OHtvbnqAhUQYKwKHUrSAicQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=corner%20cabinet%20hinge&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzICCAAyBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAFEB4yBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAFEB4yBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQBRAeMgYIABAFEB46BAgjECc6BQgAELEDOgQIABBDOgcIABCxAxBDUNuyAViYxQFg98UBaABwAHgBgAG6AogB4hGSAQg3LjExLjAuMZgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img&ei=6osDX4PPNJDAsQXKpIu4Ag&bih=947&biw=1618&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850)" should do.

Comment: That makes sense. I was having trouble picturing it until I saw your links - I have a lazy susan in a corner cabinet and simply have an angled cabinet & door (i.e., 45 degrees from the cabinets on each side).

Comment: Thanks isherwood & manassehkatz, "corner cabinet hinge homedepot" works. https://www.homedepot.com/p/35-mm-135-Degree-Corner-Folding-Cabinet-Door-Hinges-with-Installation-Screws-2-Pairs-135-2/312301555

The style looks slightly different from what I have, but it is exactly that usage. Appreciate the quick help.

Comment: FYI, found the exact hinge matching my current style after adding "invisibile" to the search keyword. https://www.homedepot.com/p/SOSS-3-8-in-x-1-in-Satin-Brass-Invisible-Hinge-100CUS4/302352600